# how to fill Self Reference Table in entity framework core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1

I am using entity framework core in my .net core 3.1 application. I have an object like

```
public class AppEntity
 {
        [Key]
        public int entity_id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string entityname { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string short_code { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int entitytype_id { get; set; }
        public int? parent_id { get; set; }        
        public AppEntity Parent { get; set; }
 }
```

How can i make my object loaded with parent object on model creating. current code at model creating is

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<AppEntity>(o => { o.HasIndex(e => e.short_code).IsUnique(true); });   
builder.Entity<AppEntity>().HasOne(j => j.Parent).WithOne().HasForeignKey<AppEntity>(f => f.parent_id);

     
}
```

I am getting exception on modelcreating as

The property or navigation 'Parent' cannot be added to the entity type 'AppEntity' because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on entity type 'AppEntity'.

Comment: **OnModelCreating** This method is called by the framework when your context is first created to build the model and its mappings in memory **not loading your data**, to load  Parent Entity with your object when fetch data just use **Include** like _context.AppEntity.Include(a=>a.Parent)

Comment: This will help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348663/c-sharp-entity-framework-how-can-i-combine-a-find-and-include-on-a-model-obje/7348694

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Entity-Framework: How can I combine a .Find and .Include on a Model Object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348663/c-sharp-entity-framework-how-can-i-combine-a-find-and-include-on-a-model-obje)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments said, the `OnModelCreating` is used to build the relationship between tables.

Before loading the object with parent object, you need to change the code in `OnModelCreating`. The `WithOne` need to specific an object.

```
    public DbSet<Entity>   entities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AppEntity> appEntities { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<AppEntity>(o => { 
            o.HasIndex(e => e.short_code)
            .IsUnique(true); 
        });
        builder.Entity<AppEntity>()
            .HasOne(j => j.Parent)
            .WithOne(i=>i.appEntity)
            .HasForeignKey<AppEntity>(f => f.parent_id);
    }
```

Because you have create the foreign key in dbcontext, so you can remove `[ForeignKey("parent_id")]`.

In addition, in model `Entity`, you should add the property `AppEntity` to reference the child object.

```
 public class Entity
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public AppEntity appEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Then, you can use `Include` to include the two objects.

```
    public virtual Entity GetById(int id) 
    { 
        
        var entity = _context.entities
             .Include(y => y.appEntity)
             .FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
        return entity; 
    }
```

Edit:

In one table, this will lead to circular references, because you have added the `parent_id` to reference the parent.

A better solution is to remove `public AppEntity Parent { get; set; }`, and remove `builder.Entity<AppEntity>().HasOne(j => j.Parent).WithOne().HasForeignKey<AppEntity>(f => f.parent_id);`.

Before inserting data into the table, query whether entity_id exists, if it exists, add it, if it does not exist, set it null. Because the primary key has its own index, the query speed is very fast.

When querying, based on these two columns, the corresponding data can be clearly processed using sub-query or associated query.

Comment: my mistake. there is no different Entity type. basically AppEntity and it contains child with similar AppEntity.

Comment: i have updated the post with new exception

Comment: @KamranShahid, the child table and the paraent table is same?

Comment: yes. that's why i have written self reference

Comment: In this scenario, you'd better to use sub-query or associated query.

Comment: Ok. Let me goolge about it. following post suggested that i could get the self reference object
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52502194/ef-core-one-way-self-referencing-entity-binding

Comment: Also checking https://dzone.com/articles/using-self-referencing-tables

Comment: Ok, I will take a look.